# What happens if a question is given 6 flags?

Tags: discussion

Does the question get transferred to the moderator or is it removed by the system itself?

Comment: I couldn't tell you from experience, because for as long as I have been moderator -- almost ten years now -- I believe we have never had that many flags accumulate before the problem was addressed.  We have been fortunate to have active moderators situated around the world in almost evenly spaced time zones (with special thanks to our Australian mods).

Answer (score 8):

According to [our help pages](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/flag-posts), when six 'spam' or 'abuse' flags are raised on a post, it's deleted automatically. (Like @whuber, I've never seen that happen.)

Comment: I've seen that happen, but it happens so fast that you hardly notice. The cases are so extreme that even the poster is unlikely to be surprised that the post was zapped. In one marginal case a poster protested that their post was, in their view, within the terms of the site, so should be answered. Somebody then commented that a question on (say) marriage guidance would be clearly out of scope, and the existence of out of scope questions showed that there must be a limit to our elasticity. But then -- bizarrely -- someone did post a question on marriage guidance, which did not survive. .